# Disable WebStorm auto add equal sign when choose a property from auto suggest

Tags: jsx, webstorm

In case of I write `<div cl`, an auto suggest window will appear with some options like `class`, `onclick`, when I press on `class` WebStorm will generate the code like this `div class=""`. But I don't want that, I just need the `class`, without `=""`

I can turn of the double/single quotes by set `None` in `Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Add for JSX Attribute and Generated quote Mark`, but don't know how to turn of the `=` as well.

https://streamable.com/wlghw8

Comment: Side note: *"I can turn of the double/single quotes by set None in..."* Actually it's `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | HTML/CSS | Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute completion` option.

Comment: There is no option for removing `=` (I do not see any). Any reasons why you do not like such completion and want to have it without any quotes or `=` symbol at all?

Comment: @LazyOne in JSX, some properties is boolean, and we just need to pass `isColumn` instead of `isColumn={true}`

Comment: Right. I found this [WEB-25537 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25537)... but it must be for standard boolean HTML attributes, not custom ones like in your case... The best workaround I may suggest right now is to hit `backspace` after completing such an attribute.

Comment: Other than that I may only suggest to make a Feature Request ticket on WebStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB providing a simple code example and reasons why it is needed etc (as usual with any feature requests) *But wait a day or so -- WebStorm support team members check this place so may provide a better suggestion on Monday*